Cannot get html with Selenium headless mode
I cannot get html of web-page with Selenium in headless mode. Without headless mode everything was ok. Below you can find code without image loading, however, it doesn't make any sense: result is the same with adding this option or not.
url = https://www.arrow.com/
What I've tried:
With Chrome:
options = Options()
user_agent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.2 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/22.0.1216.0 Safari/537.2'
options.add_argument(f'user-agent={user_agent}')
options.add_argument("--window-size=1920,1080")
options.add_argument("–-disable-gpu")
options.add_argument("--disable-blink-features")
options.add_argument("--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled")
options.add_argument('--headless')
options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])
options.add_experimental_option("prefs", {"profile.managed_default_content_settings.images": 2,})
options.add_experimental_option('useAutomationExtension', False)
s = Service(path to webdriver)
options.binary_location = "C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=s, options = options)
driver.get(url)

and FireFox
fireFoxOptions = fireFoxOptions()
fireFoxOptions.add_argument("--headless") 
fireFoxOptions.add_argument("--window-size=1920,1080")
fireFoxOptions.add_argument('--start-maximized')
fireFoxOptions.add_argument('--disable-gpu')
fireFoxOptions.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
ffservices = fireFoxService(path to gekkodriver)
ffdriver = webdriver.Firefox(options=fireFoxOptions, service = ffservices)
ffdriver.get(url)

In both cases cannot get real HTML. With Chrome simply nothing, with FireFox a page with error content.

Any particular reason you want to use headless mode?

Hi Barry. Customer requirements.

It's possible website is recognizing bot activity and blocking you. You can also try using --headless=new. Lastly, you can also try pyvirtualdisplay with Xvfb. If you cannot get it to work, let me know and I will write the example code.

--headless=new simply open web-page without any further actions. Together with common headless it opens my router settings... Xvfb requires 'fcntl' which seems to be linux-only,

The new headless mode works fine for the given website. I'm using ChromeDriver version 125.0.6422.78.
